# How to match above row value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

```
                                     want like this
```

[image] [image]

1) E column value match with above row value and display true and false.
2) Possible to add diff value above add new black row.

I have 15,000 values like this.

Ex. when come TC018 add one row above and display value false.

Comment: I believe its too hard with only excel, why can't you try it will any file handling lang.

Comment: Row add not required then not possible just display true false only on excel.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the meaning of "match with above row value"? The "2)" isn't clear either.... And you want to display True or False in E column or F? Because as you seem to do your inputs in E, it won't be possible to put True or False in the same cell

Comment: i have added second screen for which i want's

Answer (score 1):

You could run this short VBA sub on the worksheet in question.

```
Sub insertFALSE()
    Dim rw As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<~~set this worksheet properly!
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, "E").Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, "E").Value2 Then
                .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(rw, "E") = False
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

When inserting rows, it is best to work from the bottom to the top. The routine assumes that the data has been sorted with column E as the primary 'key'.

Comment: The above solution was provided prior to the 'want like this' image. Rather than modify the short procedure myself, I figured that a 'programming enthusiast' could use the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) to adjust the position of **FALSE**.

Answer (score 0):

Requires neither VBA nor formula.

Ensure your columns are labelled or insert a blank row as Row1. 
Select your data array, DATA > Outline - Subtotal, At each change in: (Column E) (or label), Use function: Count, Add subtotal to: check (ColumnE) (or label), Replace current subtotals and do not check Summary below data, OK.

DATA > Sort & Filter - Filter, to, for ColumnD, select Text Filters, Contains `Count`, OK. Enter 'false' immediately to the right of the first visible `0`, copy down to suit and blank the ColumnsD:E entries below Row1.

Remove the filter, blank F2 as required and insert a cell there with Insert..., Shift cells down, OK.